# my imageloder not change in imageview image if new image same name

Tags: android, image, android-adapter, image-load

below is my imageloader code which work fine if new image are diffrent name but if new image are same name then is not change images show old image only suppose i have image name myimage is display perfectly if i add new image in url with same name and delete previous my code again show previous image not show new image due to cache what is problem in this code help me please

```
private ImageLoader imgLoader;
private String strUrl = "http://solutionboat.com/work_2/asset/images/rifat.jpg";
private String strUrl1 = "http://solutionboat.com/work_2/asset/images/sobin.jpg";
private String strUrl2 = "http://solutionboat.com/work_2/asset/images/samol.jpg";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView target0 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.target0);
    ImageView target1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.target1);
    ImageView target2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.target2);




    imgLoader = new ImageLoader(this);

    imgLoader.displayImage(strUrl, target0);
    imgLoader.displayImage(strUrl1, target1);
    imgLoader.displayImage(strUrl2, target2);


    ViewFlipper flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper1);
    flipper.startFlipping();


}
```

}

> ImageLoader class

```
public class ImageLoader {

MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
FileCache fileCache;

private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews =
        Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());

ExecutorService executorService;

public ImageLoader(Context context) {
    fileCache = new FileCache(context);
    executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
}

final int stub_id = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;

public void displayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
    if(bitmap != null) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
    }
}

private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
    executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
}

private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
    File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

    Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
    if(b != null)
        return b;

    try {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
        Utils.copyStream(is, os);
        os.close();
        bitmap = decodeFile(f);
        return bitmap;
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}

private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
    try {
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
        int scale = 1;

        while(true) {
            if(width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE) {
                break;
            }

            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }

        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

private class PhotoToLoad{
    public String url;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
        url = u;
        imageView = i;
    }
}

class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {

    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

    PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad)) {
            return;
        }

        Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
        memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);

        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad)) {
            return;
        }

        BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
        Activity a = (Activity) photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
        a.runOnUiThread(bd);
    }
}

boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
    String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
    if(tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
        bitmap = b;
        photoToLoad = p;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;

        if(bitmap != null){
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } else {
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }
}

public void clearCahce() {
    memoryCache.clear();
    fileCache.clear();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use Picasso for any image loading/caching problems.
http://square.github.io/picasso/